# Clone a repository from GitHub

Tags: git, github, clone, git-clone

I am working on a project where I need to add a drag and drop in a div, then I started looking at libraries on drag and drop which should work on mobile devices too, and found one such library called [Dragula](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/).

I tried to clone the repository in my machine. I downloaded git which looks like this but the problem is I am not able to clone the particular library from GitHub,

[image: Git]

Comment: You are going to want to be using the git bash command line tool while in the windows environment. Its way handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have two options:

1.you can always download as project .zip if you can't setup git properly, or doesn't want to use command line.

[image: screenshot]

2.use the copy button next to the link and write in command prompt.

```
git clone paste-the-link
```

tip: click right button on mouse to paste

tip2: [how to setup git on windows](https://hackernoon.com/install-git-on-windows-9acf2a1944f0)
[image]

Comment: actually I don't want to download as I want to know how to use git

Answer (score 4):

Click that *Git Bash* icon that will open a terminal window.

Optionally create a directory and change into it, for example:

```
mkdir dev
cd dev
```

This command will clone the repository from GitHub:

```
git clone https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula.git
```

The URL to be used as a parameter for the `git clone` command is identical with the URL for the project landing page on GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click Git Bash
2. If you want clone it into `D:\\blabla` ,type `cd /d/blabla`
3. Type `git clone https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula.git`

Answer (score 0):

**Cloning a repository** (with visual studio code or any IDE)

In visual studio code type *(Ctrl+Shift+P)* or by using the Clone Repository button in the Source Control view (available when you have no folder open).

[image: Image explaination]

Know more:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to clone the repository is as follows:**

1. Goto the folder where you want to clone your repository, and press right-click and click on `Git Bash Here`:

[image]

2. Run `git clone "repo directory URL"` (but copy and paste through a mouse, ctrl+v does not work in Bash)