# Creating local git repo from remote

Tags: git

I have a remote git repo hosted in gitlab. It's got a few branches off of it already.

I am trying to pull down these branches to a local repo to work on them. For the life of me I cannot figure out how.

This seems like it should be easy but I cannot find an answer. Please let me know where I can clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clone a repository from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665389/clone-a-repository-from-github)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a local copy of a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130639/make-a-local-copy-of-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is using

```
$ git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

it downloads all your source code and all of your branches.
then you can use

```
$ git checkout <existing_branch>
```

in order to change your current branch.
you can find out more information on cloning inside [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository)

Comment: Yep that did it... I was using git switch instead of checkout. Cheers

Comment: @ThomasDuquemin using switch should work as well?