# How to clone repository onto a local machine?

Tags: git, visual-studio, docker, api, tiktok

## Cloning repository

I need this for **scraping** TikTok by using `TikTokApi` created by David Teather.

On his guideline, I have to clone repository using Docker and here are the script

```
docker build . -t tiktokapi:latest
docker run -v TikTokApi --rm tiktokapi:latest python3 your_script.py
```

I had install :

- Docker
- WSL.
- Git
- Visual Studio Code
- Visual Studio Code Remote Containers Extension

After all, what should I do? I am so confused to clone the repository. However, I am not sure with the installation of Visual Studio Code Remote Containers Extension.

Thank you in advance for your guide.

Comment: in the terminal do $git clone <your repo>

Comment: where I can find my repo ? Sorry I am not familiar worked with git ? @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: Did you try google it? Here is github project: https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api and here is example of url to use with clone: https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api.git

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clone a repository from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665389/clone-a-repository-from-github)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missleading two things:

- `docker`
- `git`

1. First you need to get this repo using `git` command THEN you will be able to use the `docker` command. `Git` will allow you to "clone" a repository. From the terminal within visual studio code or using one of the extension please do :
   `git clone <the URL of the repo>` . i.e :
   `git clone git@github.com:whatever` or `git clone https://github.com:whatever`
2. Second after that you will be able to use the `docker build .` command. **please run the docker command from the **root** of the project.**

---

Side note :

As the project owner wrote on the github main page :

> Clone this repository onto a local machine then run the following commands.
>
> ```
> docker run -v TikTokApi --rm tiktokapi:latest python3 your_script.py
> ```

that is why you need first to clone the repo

Comment: "First you need to get this repo using `git` command" --> where should I do this command ?

Comment: because if you want to build the image related to this project,  you need to pull his project by doing:
`git clone https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api.git`
then you will be able to build the image doing `docker build . -t tiktokapi:latest`

Comment: if it worked please close this question and make this answer valid

Comment: I still stuck with this and I just put off work to scrape TikTok due to another urgency. However, I would like continue this project when I have proper time.